# Data with space isn't retrieved in Mysql SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, join

i have to get a Contact in my database, but my query only returns where the name of my contact doesn't have spaces in name like: "John", if I have "John Locke" it doesn't returns, something like this:

this is my select:

```
SELECT c.nome AS nomeContato, c.cpf, c.email, c.grupo, c.informacoes_complementares,
en.logradouro, en.bairro, en.numero, en.complemento, en.cep, en.municipio, en.uf,
e.nome AS nomeEmpresa, e. cnpj, t.numero AS telefone
FROM contato AS c
INNER JOIN endereco AS en ON c.id_contato = en.id_contato
INNER JOIN empresa AS e ON c.id_contato = e.id_contato
INNER JOIN telefone AS t ON c.id_contato = t.id_contato
WHERE c.nome LIKE "Homer";
```

In this select it returns the "Homer" record, but if i try

```
SELECT c.nome AS nomeContato, c.cpf, c.email, c.grupo, c.informacoes_complementares,
    en.logradouro, en.bairro, en.numero, en.complemento, en.cep, en.municipio, en.uf,
    e.nome AS nomeEmpresa, e. cnpj, t.numero AS telefone
    FROM contato AS c
    INNER JOIN endereco AS en ON c.id_contato = en.id_contato
    INNER JOIN empresa AS e ON c.id_contato = e.id_contato
    INNER JOIN telefone AS t ON c.id_contato = t.id_contato
    WHERE c.nome LIKE "Bruce Waine";
```

It doesn't returns, but both contacts are in database, some idea?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED
I was to dumbass, my database was crashed, i've deleted it and re-builded again and now the select was working!
Thanks all

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=`?

Comment: I've tried it using "=" and it doesn't works too :(

Comment: you're sure that your table does not contain fields for each first and last name (if not, it should)? Where do you see that "Bruce Waine" has definitely be stored there? Does it return the name if you remove the joins?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to match a partial field using LIKE, you need to use the '%' wildcard characters. In your instance:-

```
WHERE c.nome LIKE "%John%";
```

That will match records for John, John Lock etc.

I expect that the failure to match 'Bruce Waine' will be down to additional characters at the beginning or end of that particular field in the data, maybe there's additional white space, carriage returns or such characters.  Try:-

```
WHERE c.nome LIKE "%Bruce Waine%";
```

Be aware that indexes support 'LIKE' matches in varying degrees.

If this doesn't solve your problem then perhaps the query isn't quite doing what you expect it to be doing.